# How to check for the PBAP connection status of a Bluetooth device while multiple devices are connected

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, phonebook

My setup is having 2 device connected.While i am disabling PBAP access from one of the device , on receive of android.bluetooth.pbapclient.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED how to know that status is changed for which Device ?

val mBluetoothManager = context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
val connectedState = mBluetoothManager.getConnectionState(device, BluetoothProfile.PBAP )